# Qt for Embedded Linux: I get an error when I run ./configure

Tags: qt, makefile

I'm new to Qt and I was planning on building Qt libraries for my ARM Cortex-A8 processor platform using ARM GNU tool chain. I'm making use of Qt for Embedded Linux (qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2) in that directory I have to first configure for ARM architecture and other options by using `./configure`. The options I'm giving are like this -

```
./configure -embedded arm -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ -little-endian -webkit -no-qt3support -no-cups -no-largefile -optimized-qmake -no-openssl -nomake tools -qt-mouse-tslib -qt-kbd-linuxinput
```

When I run this I get these series of errors. `make` is not able to find command c. The configure itself generates the `Makefile` which it runs when the ./configure command is executed, so I cannot even change from tool c to ARM GNU tools.

```
c -o qfile.o -pipe   -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -Igenerators/symbian -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include/QtCore -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/global -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/xml -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/usr/local/ti-sdk-am180x-evm/linux-devkit/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qtopia/mkspecs/linux-g++ -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT  /home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/io/qfile.cpp
make: c: Command not found
make: [qfile.o] Error 127 (ignored)
c -o qfsfileengine_unix.o -pipe   -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -Igenerators/symbian -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include/QtCore -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/global -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/xml -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/usr/local/ti-sdk-am180x-evm/linux-devkit/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qtopia/mkspecs/linux-g++ -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT  /home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/io/qfsfileengine_unix.cpp
make: c: Command not found
make: [qfsfileengine_unix.o] Error 127 (ignored)
c -o qfsfileengine_iterator_unix.o -pipe   -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -Igenerators/symbian -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include/QtCore -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/global -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/xml -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/usr/local/ti-sdk-am180x-evm/linux-devkit/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qtopia/mkspecs/linux-g++ -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT  /home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/io/qfsfileengine_iterator_unix.cpp
make: c: Command not found
make: [qfsfileengine_iterator_unix.o] Error 127 (ignored)
c -o qfsfileengine.o -pipe   -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -Igenerators/symbian -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include/QtCore -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/global -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/xml -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/usr/local/ti-sdk-am180x-evm/linux-devkit/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qtopia/mkspecs/linux-g++ -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT  /home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/io/qfsfileengine.cpp
make: c: Command not found
make: [qfsfileengine.o] Error 127 (ignored)
c -o qfsfileengine_iterator.o -pipe   -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -Igenerators/symbian -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include/QtCore -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/global -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/xml -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/usr/local/ti-sdk-am180x-evm/linux-devkit/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qtopia/mkspecs/linux-g++ -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT  /home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/io/qfsfileengine_iterator.cpp
make: c: Command not found
make: [qfsfileengine_iterator.o] Error 127 (ignored)
c -o qregexp.o -pipe   -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -Igenerators/symbian -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include/QtCore -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/global -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/xml -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/usr/local/ti-sdk-am180x-evm/linux-devkit/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qtopia/mkspecs/linux-g++ -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT  /home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/tools/qregexp.cpp
make: c: Command not found
make: [qregexp.o] Error 127 (ignored)
c -o qvector.o -pipe   -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -Igenerators/symbian -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include/QtCore -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/global -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/xml -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/usr/local/ti-sdk-am180x-evm/linux-devkit/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qtopia/mkspecs/linux-g++ -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT  /home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/tools/qvector.cpp
make: c: Command not found
make: [qvector.o] Error 127 (ignored)
c -o qbitarray.o -pipe   -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -Igenerators/symbian -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include/QtCore -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/global -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/xml -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/usr/local/ti-sdk-am180x-evm/linux-devkit/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qtopia/mkspecs/linux-g++ -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT  /home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/tools/qbitarray.cpp
make: c: Command not found
make: [qbitarray.o] Error 127 (ignored)
c -o qdir.o -pipe   -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -Igenerators/symbian -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include/QtCore -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/global -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/xml -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/usr/local/ti-sdk-am180x-evm/linux-devkit/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qtopia/mkspecs/linux-g++ -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT  /home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/io/qdir.cpp
make: c: Command not found
make: [qdir.o] Error 127 (ignored)
c -o qdiriterator.o -pipe   -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -Igenerators/symbian -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/include/QtCore -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/global -I/home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/xml -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/usr/local/ti-sdk-am180x-evm/linux-devkit/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qtopia/mkspecs/linux-g++ -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT  /home/sandeep/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/src/corelib/io/qdiriterator.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

I did two things in order to get past this issue.

First, in the `qmake.conf` file for my given platform I ensured I had the entire path to the compiler and other tools setup.  I was using a modified version of the `linux-arm-g++`. For instance, my compiler was at: `/home/lucid/compiler/linux-gnueabi-g++`.  So this is what I put in for QMAKE_CXX, QMAKE_LINK and QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB.  Similarly for QMAKE_CC.

```
 QMAKE_CC          = /home/lucid/compiler/linux-gnueabi-gcc
 QMAKE_CXX         = /home/lucid/compiler/linux-gnueabi-g++
 QMAKE_LINK        = /home/lucid/compiler/linux-gnueabi-g++
 QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB  = /home/lucid/compiler/linux-gnueabi-g++
```

Also be sure to set the includes to the right sub path `include(../common/linux.conf)` may need to be `include(../../common/linux.conf)`.

Second, I set the `PATH=location_of_compiler:$PATH` so that the libraries and compiler would be pulled from the right location.  I tested this with a simple build of a HelloWorld app before trying to compile all of QT.

I don't know if both are necessary, where just the `PATH` may be sufficient, but it seemed to me that I needed to do them both.